# Two worlds merge together

Tags: humans, culture, survival, worldbuilding-resources, invasion

**There are the two worlds A and B, which are light years apart.**

In the 22nd century, a super-intelligent race with cutting edge technology from the world A tries to invade a world B which only has 21st century level science and technology.

After invading world B, the super-intelligent race A creates concepts of fear, dignity, morality, and self-preservation, and  also replaces the culture.

The invaded world B is affected by environmental collapse, unending wars on every continent, every living human in this primitive world is also affected by diseases, and all its resources are also taken.

**My Question:** Is there any possible way that the human species on the invaded world B, that is greatly negatively affected, to fight back against the invaders and retain back its culture, power and resources?

Comment: Can the people who down vote leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: Down-voted and voted to close because this is much to broad... unless the wording is followed to the letter: "Is there any possible way". Yes, there is a possible way. Because you cannot prove there is no such possible way. And @CandiedOrange just gave a very well known example of this exact scenario. Apart from that I would like to remind that no story was ever driven by perfect characters that does everything right. Stories are driven by character flaws and mistakes. Sure, some such flaws are just dumb ( http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0286106/combined ) but you can do better, I am sure. :)

Comment: @Bellerephon,your presence automatically,liberates others.

Comment: @Bellerephon In the absence of an explanationary comment, the canonical downvote reason, as can be seen by hovering over the downvote button is: *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.*

Comment: It is not your job to take away somebody else's right to vote. Only down-vote if you thought that it was a unclear question/answer, not because you disagreed with somebody else's comment.

Comment: The real problem is that any explanation belongs in the question, not these comments.  When you vote please consider the comments something likely to be deleted because they just may be.

Comment: Stories in which this occur are myraid.  It even happens in real life from time to time.  However, in every case, there is no one magical "road-map-to-rebellion" which we could write down for you.  May I suggest as a possible duplicate, http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/51461/how-can-a-revolution-occur-if-the-leadership-class-is-indestructible/51466#51466 and my answer there, which explores how you might come up with such a rebellion for your story.

Answer (score 1):

While H G Wells writing in 1896 could dispel technologically superior Martian invaders with the aid of earthly microbes, this isn't an option to the more sophisticated writer of today.

Considering the invaders from world A are super-intelligent and have far superior technology the sheer level of devastation to world B and its inhabitants is so great that it doesn't seem plausible for the people of world B to survive, let alone, fight back comprehensively against the invasion.

World B has environmental collapse and its resources taken. The people of world B have been psychologically attacked, their culture has been destroyed, their bodies are diseased, and they are locked in wars on every continent.

Unless the invaders from world A simply go away and leave world B in peace, for it to hopefully recover and allow its inhabitants to rebuild their civilization it is doomed by the invasion.

Comment: Maybe they'll let us build casino's.

Comment: Casino’s *what*? You need a noun phrase after the possessive, like “the casono's parking lot”. That’s going to bug me all night now!

Comment: Who or what is the casono? Let alone his, hers, its or their involvement with parking lots.